# Issue while creating BroadcastReceiver inside Service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a service in which I have registered a simple Broadcast receiver to check whether the device is plugged/unplugged from the charger. I started the service by calling,

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this,TestReceiverService.class); 
      startService(intent);
```

TestReceiverService.class

```
public class TestReceiverService extends Service {
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerTestReceiver();
}


private void registerTestReceiver() {

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mTestReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

public BroadcastReceiver mTestReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Event triggered--------", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};}
```

But I didn't get the toast when the device is plugged / unplugged. I have tried to call this broadcast receiver directly from activity and it worked.But inside service it is not working. I am not much familiar with service. Please suggest a solution

Thanks in advance.

Comment: onCreate will call only once, so it will execute once..
whenever any client call startService() or bindService(), then service will return the available binder, that means next time won't execute onCreate() again .. so for your case this toast has displayed only once

Comment: did you add your service in your androidmanifest.xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it only once, then your logic is okay.

`onCreate` will call only once, so it will execute one time. Whenever any client calls `startService()` or `bindService()`, then that service will return the available binder and the `onServiceConnected()` call back will called.

This means that next time it won't execute `onCreate()` again, so for your case this `toast` has displayed only once.

So `onStartCommand()` or `onBind()` will call directly whenever a user tries to call `startService()` or `bindService()`.

Or if you want to display the toast whenever you connect with service, then you have to do either in `onStart()` or `onBind()`

Comment: I am not even getting the toast for atleast once. I have already tried using onStart(). didn't make any difference

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it's only called once... it's called whenever a a service instance doesn't exist i.e. `onDestroy` was called https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#LifecycleCallbacks

Comment: absolutely, that is the inner meaning.. if onDestroy() called means definitely onCreate() will call..

supose onStartCommand executed, that does not mean onDestroy() will call soon.

if we are binding the service, then onDestroy() will call when all client remove its connection with service .

Comment: @poojarc from where you are calling startService() or bindService() ??
I mean in which class and method ?

Comment: @poojarc, did you add your service in your androidmanifest.xml ?

Comment: Oops.. sorry.. I haven't. That was the reason. Thanks for helping @Navas.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have the wrong context, try using `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Thanks for your time @Ryan